# Form Response Edit & Generate Unique Number Script Not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Please help me understand where I am going wrong. I am trying to run a simple form response edit script and generate unique serial number GAS taken from Internet. I also checked it in ChatGPT and Bard but its says the scripts are correct. Then I checked all the other parameters like accuracy of columns and sheet names in variable, which are also correct. I tested the form edit URL GAS by creating trigger of the function on "form submit".
Hence I do not know where I am going wrong. I am getting this error when I check failed executions :-

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getEditResponseUrl')
at NewgeteditLink(url:7:34)

File Link :- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l_jKmw4KybeXi9TwoKxKx33gld9REwRuthG__6gaU-o/edit#gid=166056455
Form Link :- https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfbpUYwiGFlwCmV_WZK51IEa6xmV1oPPlRxmLZY9GNrZr5VkQ/viewform

A) Below is the form edit URL script:-

```
var sheets_ID = "1_aaQEzGxkuK90J4An1d2VCG0M5UjSpebfRf2wZ4eGec";
var Data_SS_Name = 'Responses';
var Col_Edit_Link = 15;
var Col_Timestamp = 1; // Example: Add a timestamp column

function NewgeteditLink(e) {
var responseUrl = e.response.getEditResponseUrl();
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheets_ID);
var dataSS = ws.getSheetByName(Data_SS_Name);
var lastRow = dataSS.getLastRow() + 1; // Since we'll insert a new row

dataSS.getRange(lastRow, Col_Timestamp).setValue(new Date()); // Add timestamp

dataSS.getRange(lastRow, Col_Edit_Link).setValue(responseUrl);

}

B) Below is the script for generating unique key:- `
function generateUniqueSerialNumber() {
Get the active sheet
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Responses");

Get the last row index
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

Get the previous serial number
var previousSerialNumber = sheet.getRange('A' + lastRow).getValue();

Generate a new unique serial number based on the previous one
var newSerialNumber = generateNextSerialNumber(previousSerialNumber);

Set the new serial number in column A of the last row
sheet.getRange('A' + lastRow).setValue(newSerialNumber);
}

Function to generate the next serial number based on the previous one
function generateNextSerialNumber(previousSerialNumber) {
Assuming the serial number is a string containing numeric characters
var numericPart = parseInt(previousSerialNumber, 10);

Increment the numeric part by 1
var newNumericPart = numericPart + 1;

Convert the new numeric part back to a string
var newSerialNumber = newNumericPart.toString();

return newSerialNumber;
}
```

Comment: If your error of `Cannot read properties of undefined` occurred at `var responseUrl = e.response.getEditResponseUrl();`, I'm worried that you might have directly run the function `NewgeteditLink` with the script editor. If my guess was correct, such an error occurs because of no event object `e`. From `I tested the form edit URL GAS by creating trigger of the function on "form submit".`, if you have installed the function `NewgeteditLink` as OnSubmit trigger, please submit the Google Form. By this, the function is automatically run. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: I have installed the trigger on Form submit for function NewgeteditLink and I have submitted the form many times to check. I think something is wrong with Timestamp column

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I have installed the trigger on Form submit for function NewgeteditLink and I have submitted the form many times to check. I think something is wrong with Timestamp column`, I couldn't understand your situation. But, I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. But, about `I think something is wrong with Timestamp column`, I woulld like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getEditResponseUrl') at NewgeteditLink`? By this, I would like to confirm it.